# Not able to check does button is enabled or disabled

Tags: angular, protractor

I am trying to select button and check does he have added "disabled" attribute.

Code:

```
expect(audiencePage.saveAudienceBtn.getAttribute('disabled')).toBe(true);
```

Here is intresting error:

```
-Expected 'true' to be true.
Executed 7 of 7 specs (1 FAILED) in 18 secs.
[13:44:18] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:44:18] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[13:44:18] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[13:44:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Any Idea, why I get this error?

Comment: Because you're getting the *value* of the attribute, apparently the string `'true'`, not whether or not that attribute is set (which is what triggers the actual behaviour, the value doesn't matter).

Comment: yees, thank you for reply!

Comment: I've removed the angularjs tag, assuming that this question is about Angular (due to you asking more questions about Angular). I've also removed some other tags that are rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
expect(audiencePage.saveAudienceBtn.getAttribute('disabled')).toBe(true);
```

to `expect(audiencePage.saveAudienceBtn.getAttribute('disabled')).toBe('true');`

The reason for the error is that you were trying to compare boolean and string.